# How do I generate a new object after pressing the space bar?

Tags: java, swing, object

I created a "bullet" that moves in the positive x direction after pressing the space bar. It resets at a certain position once it goes off screen. However, how can I make it so that *every* time I press the space bar, a bullet is shot? Is creating a new object necessary, or can I keep the same object but instantiate a second time while the first is still animating (I feel like that wouldn't work). I'm a newbie so any help is appreciated.

**Edit: My code thus far. The first is for the PlayState and the second is the ball class**

```
public class GameMain {
private static final String GAME_TITLE = "LoneBall (Chapter 5)";
public static final int GAME_WIDTH = 800;
public static final int GAME_HEIGHT = 450;
public static Game sGame;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame(GAME_TITLE);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false); // Prevents manual resizing of window
    sGame = new Game(GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT);
    frame.add(sGame);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setIconImage(Resources.iconimage); // This is the new line!
}
```

}

```
public class PlayState extends State {

private static final int PADDLE_WIDTH = 15;
private static final int PADDLE_HEIGHT = 60;

private Ball ball;
private static final int BALL_DIAMETER = 10;

private int playerScore = 0;
private Font scoreFont;

@Override
public void init() {

    scoreFont = new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 25);
    ball = new Ball(300, 200, BALL_DIAMETER, BALL_DIAMETER);
}

@Override
public void update() {

    ball.update();
    if (ball.isDead()) {
        playerScore++;
        ball.reset();
    }

    //adjust player score here
}

@Override
public void render(Graphics g) {
    // Draw Background

    g.setColor(Resources.darkRed);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, GameMain.GAME_WIDTH,
            GameMain.GAME_HEIGHT);
    // Draw Separator Line

    // Draw Paddles
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.drawImage(Resources.gun, 0, 150, 300, 200, null);


    // Draw Ball
    g.setColor(Color.yellow);
    g.fillOval(ball.getX(), ball.getY(), ball.getWidth(), ball.getHeight());


    // Draw UI
    g.setFont(scoreFont); // Sets scoreFont as current font
    g.drawString("" + playerScore, 350, 40); // Draws String using current
                                                // font
}

@Override
public void onClick(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onKeyPress(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
        ball.velX = 10;
        }
}

@Override
public void onKeyRelease(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP
            || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {

    }
 }
}
```

Then the ball class:

```
public class Ball {

private int x, y, width, height;
public int velX;
private Rectangle oval;

public Ball(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    final int velX = 0;
    oval = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
}

public void update() {
    x += velX;
}

private void updateRect() {
    oval.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
}


public boolean isDead() {
    return (x < 0 || x + width > GameMain.GAME_WIDTH || y < 0 || y > GameMain.GAME_HEIGHT);
}

public void reset() {
    x = 300;
    y = 200;
    velX = 0;

}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public int getWidth() {
    return width;
}

public int getHeight() {
    return height;
}

public Rectangle getRect() {
    return oval;
}
}
```

Comment: How about showing us what you have tried?

Comment: What GUI library: Swing? AWT? SWT? Something else? Your question unfortunately is very short on important details.

Comment: AWT is what I am using.

Comment: AWT? So you're creating a Frame or an Applet? I'm still not clear. My answer was for Swing not AWT, in other words for JFrames, JPanels and JApplets.

Comment: It is Swing, my bad.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm new to StackOverflow and pretty new to Java so I apologize for not providing enough information. I believe my question will help serve future learners in the future, so I appreciate you taking your time to help.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: BTW - avoid using 'magic numbers' - `scoreFont = new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 25);` should be `scoreFont = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, 25);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make no mention of your GUI library, so I'll assume that it's a Swing application, but hopefully you'll fix this by giving us a **lot** more information and your current pertinent code.

One solution is to use [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) to bind a bullet creation action to a spacebar press. This gets around the issue of KeyListeners and focus problems that plague their use.

e.g.,

```
// assuming displayed a main JPanel called mainJPanel
ActionMap actionMap = mainJPanel.getActionMap();
int condition = JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW;
InputMap inputMap = mainJPanel.getInputMap(condition);

// assuming a class, CreateBulletAction, that extends AbstractAction
// and that creates your bullets
inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, 0), "space");
actionMap.put("space", new CreateBulletAction());
```

Comment: Hmm I see what you're doing there! So I created the Ball under render(Graphics g). How would I do it with your method?

Comment: @mckamike: no you should only do drawing within your rendering/painting methods, not object creation or program state change.